# why did my input value change from 0.01 to 0.1

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a class named decimalnumber. I used it so my input only allow number and . 
but if i input 0.01 value, it becomes 0.1
any idea why is it happen and how to fix that?
i'm still new with this, thank you

This is my script

```
$(".decimalnumber").keypress(function (e) {
    if ((e.charCode >= 48 && e.charCode <= 57) || (e.charCode == 0) || (e.charCode == 46))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
});
```

This is the html code

```
<input type="text" name="qty" class="decimalnumber" value="">
```

Comment: it not changing , share html too and related code ?

Comment: This is working fine when i tested

Comment: [Seems to be working fine](https://jsfiddle.net/gnL2fun7/)

Comment: still you are missing related js code , related `.decimalnumber` `.qty` or `#qty` ?

Comment: when the cursor not in the textbox the value changed

Comment: i try deleted class qty and the id, but it still like that. So i concluded that the problem is there

Comment: share other js code which is related to `.decimalnumber .qty or #qt` search in your js file  and share ?